# Using SalesLogixPortalDeploymentUtility

Tags: deployment, utility, saleslogix

Not sure if anyone has much experience working with SalesLogix, but I've been working with this 3rd-party utility in attempts to deploy a VFS without the need for Application Architect.  I wasn't able to find any documentation for it and it seems that it's missing a bunch of files it needs to run (I already spent some time feeding it all the necessary DLLs it needed in the places it needed them in).  Please let me know if you can lend any insight.  Currently, I'm able to connect to the database, but the deployment is not happening.  Here are some of the initial errors from the log file:

Error running transform: System.IO.FileLoadException: **Unable to load file, '\Entity Model\Process Orchestration Support\ProcessInstanceStatus\OnAfterDelete.method.xml'**. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Sage.Platform.Orm.Entities.OrmEntityMethod'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'PreExecuteTargets'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Sage.Platform.Orm.Entities.OrmMethodTarget'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Sage.Platform.Orm.Entities.OrmMethodTargetSnippet'. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: **A strongly-named assembly is required.** (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the ProcessOrchestration deployment, will it finish the other target deployment(s)? I've never used that product before, but I'm taking a stab at it anyway.